# Center Image in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to place an image in the center of the page. vertically and horizontally, regardless of screen size. How is this possible?

```
<label class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="logo.jpg">
</label>
```

```
img {
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's an image explaining what I'm trying to do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKJTG.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve is with `flexbox`. Try this

```css
.img-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<label class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="logo.jpg">
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `flexbox` to align elements. See the snippet below:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.img-wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /*align items vertically*/
  justify-content: center; /*align item horizontally*/
}

img {
   width: 50vh;
   height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<label class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F61yBDRJCKBL._SL500_.jpg&f=1&nofb=1">
</label>
```

More on `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).